# Two LDOs influencing each other despite only being connected through Vcc

Tags: ldo, gate-driving

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis and running into a problem with two of my LDOs nut running as intended. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to share the schematic so I will draw the parts of the schematic, wich I deem important.
[image]

Both LDOs are LT1129. The adjust pin(ADJ) is internally connected to always be at 3,75V. They both are connected to two different gate drivers. As long as those gate drivers aren't enabled, both LDOs do their job as intended and the outputs are around 20V and 15V as intended. If now the gate driver, to which the output of LDO2 ist connected, gets enabled, everything still works as intended. If on the other hand the Gatedriver of LDO1 gets enabled, LDO1 still functions as intended but the ADJ pin of LDO2 gets pulled up to 5V. Also a rustle can be heard.

Now I'm clueless what could cause the problem. It's very likely not a power issue, since Vcc(27V) is supplied by a DC/DC converter who is only drawing 0,5W of power during the phenomenon occurring. Do you have any idea what could cause the problem? In the future I intend to run both LDOs at the same time which isn't possible currently.

Comment: What type of capacitor did you use for C2 and C4? Could you link its datasheet?

Comment: I think there are connections missing to provide you an answer. Also even this diagram is missing a ground so regulators would not work. Also is that really the fixed 3V3 version or the ADJ version if you talk about ADJ pin and 3.75V?

Comment: How did you make the measurement when seeing 5 V? (Worrying about oscillation.)

Comment: @periblepsis I measured the ADJ pin with an oscilloscope after the output voltage peak of the gate driver, after running both drivers at the same time, showed 19.5 V instead of the hoped for 15V

Comment: @Lucas Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @JonathanS. I used some altium showed were available instead of considering which kind of capacitor they were, since the data sheet of the LDO just specified the capacity

Comment: The LT1129 datasheet specifies the ESR of the capacitor needed for stability, not just capacity. What capacitor did you select?

Comment: @Justme Sorry I was dumb. I just looked at my schematic again. I used the LT1129 not the 3.3 version

Comment: @user1850479 Its a ceramic capacitor from Kemet size 0805 but I can't currently find which one I chose

Edit: I'm very certain I looked at the corresponding voltage levels but I currently can't find one which fits that mold

Comment: @user1850479 I'm now positive I used this one: https://datasheet.ciiva.com/24216/c2012x5r1h335k125ab-264893-24216187.pdf?src-supplier=Mouser
I can say it for sure when I can enter the intranet of my institute on Monday

Comment: Ceramic is a good choice. The value is slightly too small given the loss of capacitance with DC voltage, but I doubt that is your problem.

Comment: The interaction and higher output voltage suggests that the 20V regulator output is being coupled to the 15V regulator output by something outside of the schematic you have provided, perhaps through a diode or equivalent. Maybe you have an unintended short or a design issue that we cannot guess from the provided information.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I swapped the resistances R1 and R3 and than the same thing just happens to the other LDO which wasn’t affected before. I’m really clueless currently

Comment: Can you measure any connection between the two outputs?

Comment: @CL. Thats a good question. I will measure that on Monday when I have access again.

Comment: Does anyone think that it could have anything to do with the value of the resistances?. The higher ones don't seem to be affected. I can't find a logical explanation for that.